# xPath For Specific Element

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm scraping SuperLawyers.com for name and address info of lawyers. It's scraping all of the correct data except the phone number. The profile pages have the phone number twice, of course I'm happy with extracting either of them. An example of a page:

https://profiles.superlawyers.com/massachusetts/somerville/lawyer/wyckoff-nissenbaum/e854f9a4-28d2-46e6-bf69-dee74c7ffdb1.html

My xPath: `phone = response.xpath('//div[@id="lawyer_phone_button"]//text()').extract()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not skip the `a` tag in this case. Use below

```
phone = response.xpath('//div[@id="lawyer_phone_button"]/a/text()').extract()
```

Works on the page you posted